# Showing $\frac{d^6y}{dx^6}$ using $\frac{d^4y}{dx^4}$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

---

I found :

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = -x \sin x + 2 \cos x$$

$$\frac{d^4y}{dx^4}=x \sin x - 4 \cos x$$

---

I have seen the pattern, but how do I use these results to find $$\frac{d^6y}{dx^6}$$

---

*Establishing the general formula is a separate question,which is not what  the question wants me to do for this particular first part of the question. Since it is second part. Also I have successfully established the expression, so there is no need of any explanations for the second part, I posted that part to show  that I can't use the second part to answer first*

Hence I am looking for a different method. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is slightly difficult to know exactly how the question should be interpreted, but perhaps  you could answer it something like this:
\begin{align}\frac{\mathrm{d}^6}{\mathrm{d}x^6}y = \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}\underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}^4}{\mathrm{d}x^4}y}_{\text{Known.}} &= \\\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}\big[-4\cos x+x\sin x\big] &=\\ -4\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}\big[\cos x\big] + \underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}\big[x\sin x\big]}_{\text{Known.}} &=\\ 4\cos x +2\cos x-x\sin x &=\\ 6\cos x - x\sin x
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you  :) this presentation is much better :)

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're venturing into differential equations territory here.  Given $\frac{d^4y}{dx^4}$, the natural way to find $\frac{d^6y}{dx^6}$ is to differentiate twice.  Of course, there is a shortcut here once you find $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$.  Note that

$$y+\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=2\cos x$$

Differentiating both sides twice gives

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{d^4y}{dx^4}=-2\cos x$$

Given this formula, you could solve for the fourth derivative once you know the second.  Then repeat the process by differentiating this equation twice more.

Answer (score 0):

Hint; Can you generalise this to $$\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2n}y}{\mathrm{d}x^{2n}}\;\;\;?$$

Comment: I have generalized it, but this is the second part of the question which I have proved successfully, so this question I have posted is before that.

Comment: So no the question is not expecting me to use that in the before part (this part)

Comment: @TheArtist the next thing that comes to mind is using the operator $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}$ once on the $4^{\text{th}}$ derivative of $y$ wrt to $x$. There is no restriction to show it directly according to your pic.

Comment: You mean to keep differentiating the 4th derivative the normal way we do ?

Comment: @TheArtist Yes it seems it makes you calculate the $2^{\text{nd}}$, $4^{\text{th}}$ and $6^{\text{th}}$ derivative to make you see the patern as a hint for the second question.

Comment: It's fairly obvious that that's not what the question wants, isn't it? :) also if it's fairly  that elementary obvious if that was the case , I wouldn't post this question in the first place.

Comment: No look at the question, we are supposed to find the second and fourth derivative. And then **show** the 6th derivative.

Comment: @TheArtist then my contribution is done, let's wait for more answers.

Comment: Yep, even I do not know any method other than the two ways you told :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $y=x \sin x$ then $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = -x \sin x + 2 \cos x$.

If $y=x \sin x - 4 \cos x$ then $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} =$?

Edit: Apparently what I wrote wasn't clear, so here's a slightly more explicit answer:

> If $y=x \sin x - 4 \cos x$ then $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = (-x \sin x + 2 \cos x)+\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(-4 \cos x)$.

Comment: An explanation of the down vote would be great so that I can see if I'm missing anything.

Comment: This approach calculates the sixth derivative using the second and fourth derivative (plus calculating the second derivative of cos(x)), so it seems to be exactly what The Artist wants.

Comment: Re read my question :) , the question isn't about calculating :)

Comment: Where have u used both $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ and $\frac{d^4}{dx^4}$ in your answer?

Comment: @TheArtist: It's obvious, I would say.

Comment: @TonyK , his answer is if the question asked simply to find the 2nd , 4th and 6th derivative. That's not what the question is asking , right? :)

Comment: @TheArtist: I've added a bit to the answer to try to make it clearer what I mean. If it hasn't helped then please tell me and I'll make some more changes.

Comment: @TheArtist: I can't imagine _what_ you want, if this is not it!

Comment: Understood :) Thank you :)